# How to call one notebook from another notebook in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, emr-serverless

I'm newbie to AWS EMR and I have been trying to call test1.ipynb notebook in test2.ipynb notebook.
But I'm not able to do it.

In the past I have worked on databrick where I was able to achieve this using %run ./test2 magic command. is there something similar in AWS EMR?